# Parse Floating point number Assembly

Tags: parsing, floating-point, mips, ieee-754

Hi im trying to make a custom procedure in MIPS for parsing a float (32-bit) from a string in ieee-754. Im following the steps frm [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Converting_from_decimal_representation_to_binary32_format).
The problem is that i can't handle the fact that the integer part could be greater than 2^32, because im getting overflow in mulou instruction:

```
int_part:
    lb $t1, 0($a0)
    add $a0, $a0, 1
    beq $t1, '.', fract_part
    mulou $s2, $s2, 10
    add $s2, $s2, $t1
    subi $s2, $s2, '0'
    j int_part
```

In the code above id like to store the integer-part of input in $s2, so i be able to normalize it and then convert it into binary (as says in wikipedia)